# How to access multiple database dynamically using Entity framework 6.1(Power Tool Beta 4) with ASP.NET web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I've created a project using Asp.net Mvc 4 => Web api...

I have integrated Angularjs in it. and so I'm using single page app.

I'm also using entity framework 6.1.

For Database connectivity, I'm using Entity framework Power tool beta 4 by which I target particular DB and generate DBcontext.

Now scenario is:

There is one other application by which end user can register himself. When he does it, new Database is generated into Database server with "ProjectName+ClientName" name eg. MISSteve,MISJohn...

This new user entry goes into MISDBManager Database which is already there in Database server with new connectionstring and new user.

So, This MISDBManager has clientName and relevant connectionString.

So overall. In Database, One MISDBManager which has different registered users with DB Connection strings.

eg,

```
   (ClientName)  -          (ConnectionString) 

         BV      - data source=pdev-3\xyz;initial catalog=MISBv;integrated security=true 
         Steve   - data source=pdev-3\xyz;initial catalog=MISSteve;integrated security=true
```

Now My problem and question is,

When I run my application, logging page comes. user enters his credentials. Now With Power Tool Beta 4, through reverse engineering, I have already generated MISDBManagerDBCOntext against which I check whether credential is valid or not. Till here everything works perfectly fine.

But what I want is, If username & password are valid, I want to connect that valid user to his relevant DB.

As I have stated I'm using EF 6.1, PowerTool Beta 4 and with Reverse Engineering I can only target fixed client. Which is not valid for my Project.

I want to connect valid client to his one DB (generated & stored with different tables into Database server).

with static approach, I can target one client. But when it comes to dynamic approach I dont't know how to do it.

Means, As shown here if BV(ClientName) gets logged in, i can redirect him to Dashboard because I have generated his fixed MISBvDBContext. 
But If other user gets logged I can do it.
If i'm having thousand users I can't generate thousand DBcontext. so dynamic approach is needed to connect client to his Database.

Please help me to get this things done. Please let me know if other way is there to connect client to his DB.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to rethink your approach. What compelling reason can you have to create a separate database for every user? And, no, unless you know your database name and create the context beforehand, you will not be able to achieve what you want, but I strongly believe that your solution is wrong in so many ways

Comment: you can suggest different way. Please let me know how to change targeted DB with available connectionstring using EF.

Comment: Suggest a different way for connecting to a database-per-user which is created dynamically? Nope. You need to rethink why you need this architecture and as I iterated earlier, unless you know your databases and create the context before running your application, your approach wont work

Comment: When user is created, his DB is also created.I want when this user gets logged in, he is able to access his DB only having all required tables(already created in DB schema)...

Comment: Why do you need a separate database per user? This is bad design, period. What will happen if you have 1000s of users? how are you going to maintain and support all these databases? what's different for each user that demands a separate database?